# Load Application on Windows StartUp

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, windows

I'm developing an Windows DLL and I want to know more about windows c++ programming.

The first problem I'm facing is know how to load my application when Windows is loading?

There is any guide on Windows Documentation describing that?

Comment: A DLL is not an application, it won't load by itself.

Comment: I know, but I have a load problem when my DLL is called!  I can create a service to avoid reload every time my DLL is used.

Comment: No, you can't. It will still be loaded whenever an application needs your DLL.

Comment: Yes, but the data my DDL loads can be loaded in another service, and all the process too.

Comment: And it will be loaded repeatedly. At startup would just be one extra time, slowing things down even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know how to do this:

1) You can create a shortcut to the .exe in the autostart folder

2) You can add the .exe in the registry at `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Answer (score 0):

You can load your application when windows startup by copying your application to **startup folder** please refer http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Also refer http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7